# Search globally in Stack Exchange

Tags: feature-request, search

In Stack Overflow, there is this [search page](https://stackoverflow.com/search), where I can do advanced searches such as `hasaccepted:0 user:me` (- find all my questions without an accepted answer).

In Stack Exchange, there is also a [search page](https://stackexchange.com/search), but it is different - it uses Google custom search, and the advanced search from above does not work.

Thus, there is no way to find all my questions without an accepted answer, in all sites.

Is there a way to do advanced search such as `hasaccepted:0 user:me`, in all the Stack Exchange sites at once?

Comment: What exactly is the use case for this? I wracked my brain trying to think of some reason you would want to search all sites for your posts, but I couldn't think of one.

Comment: @jmac reviewing old question to see if no "accepted" marks was omitted by accident seems honourable goal. And I can see how someone can forget or not know if specific PHP question is on Drupal Answers or Stack Overflow, so global search may have additional uses. It's not like there is a clean cut between topics all the time.

Comment: If this is something you have to do regularly, then why not use the api to do it programmatically? If it isn't regular, why not just do it site by site? How frequent of an issue is this to justify development time?

Comment: @jmac this becomes more and more frequent, as I register to more sites in the SE network. In the last week, I asked questions in 7 different SE sites. It becomes more and more difficult to remember what I asked where, whether I accepted or not, etc...

Comment: When an answer appears to a question, you get a notification. If the answer solves your problem, why would you not mark it as accepted then? Furthermore, even if you don't mark it as accepted immediately, where is the harm? I really see this as a solution looking for a problem...

Comment: @jmac I don't mark it immediately because I need time to test and see if it works. When there are so many answers to test, it is easy to forget one or two of them. This may frustrate the people that answered.

Comment: I started work on this months ago...spent a whole 2 hours.  It needs a lot of love, mostly in the result ordering.  As soon as time allows I'll try and give it the needed love for user testing.

Comment: I don't suppose it's something stackexchange would support, but I personally think it would have been nice to search for users across the various SE sites.

Answer (score 2):

This is now possible with the Data Explorer. See for example rene's answer here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/261594/165110